# Should I avoid having secret keys in a private git repository?

Tags: git, security, github, configuration, config

Currently I have all my various keys in a config file which is version controlled on a PRIVATE repo. The code is on a trusted side (Github). Should I avoid version controlling this config file in git?

If not, then how would you share this file with the development team ?

Comment: Why should you share your keys with others members of the team? Cannot you just register a key for every member?

Comment: API keys, secret values for serialisation og deserialisation, maybe database credentials and such. I won't have specific values for each contributor. This is also for production code

Comment: Remember that every online service may be hacked anytime. Therefore even private repositories can then be exposed to an attacker. Regarding your question: ask yourself what damage an attacker could do with those values and how difficult it would be to get those values without reading your private repo (e.g. extracting from your application).

Comment: @Robert If GitHub is hacked, the loss of intellectual property (the code base) would be bad enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing a private key is always a bad practice... As an answer to your question there is nothing wrong with git as a key container, it is quite safe, even if safety depends on other elements, such as the security level of the git host. But you have no control on the key after another developer/user get it, so YES, as a good practice you should avoid this. Depending on your case maybe you can choose another solution, for example set up a one time password generator.

Comment: For example I have API keys to google maps. I don't want these to get out, but I would trust my developers with it - and I don't see a way to create a development environment without exposing some keys to the developers. Keep in mind that there is no 'developer specific' keys in this file - like personal passwords

Comment: @JonasPraem, you should have development keys to use in development. There's no need for anybody (including you) to have production keys in their development environment.