# keep my project key.properties and .jks file in Github

Tags: flutter, github, android-app-signing

I want to keep my project key.properties and .jks file in GitHub, but whenever I committed after generating these files, these files don't commit.

I know it might be risky to keep these files on GitHub but my repositories are private and only my collages have access to them.

So, I want to keep these files in my GitHub repositories.

any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Check `android/.gitignore`, it has the following lines by default:

```
key.properties
**/*.keystore
**/*.jks
```

Remove or comment them.

Comment: yes, git it. it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: sure you can remove the file from being ignored in git. This is however bad practice, even on private repo [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002547/should-i-avoid-having-secret-keys-in-a-private-git-repository). Instead pass it to new developers and add it as @Ravi Limbani suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed very risky to commit those files.

If you really want to commit them and can't here are two possible reasons:

- You might have a rule in your `.gitignore` that says to not commit those files.
- You might have an extension/bot on your Github Repository to check if these files are committed (GitGardian for example) and you might want to remove it for this repository in this specific case.

Comment: I'm not using GitGuardian and can you please thoroughly explain me which rules are restricting these files to commit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is not recommended to do in the industry standard code. But if you really want to add those mentioned files. You can simply force and push to your github private repo.
For example; git add android/app/[file_name].jks android/[file_name].properites -f

Provide the specific path for the file and use '-f' while adding, this will force to append those files in the commit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write below code in build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
        release {

            file("keystore/signin.properties").with { propFile ->
                if (propFile.canRead()) {
                    def properties = new Properties()
                    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))
                    storeFile file("keystore/${properties['storeFile']}")
                    storePassword properties['storePassword']
                    keyAlias properties['keyAlias']
                    keyPassword properties['keyPassword']
                } else {
                    println "Unable to read signing.properties"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And save your jks and .properties like below screen in keystore folder

[image]

Also write your jks detail in signin.properties like below

[image]

Comment: i have the same